# A tool or browser which changes the IP Address (Not like a single VPN, lots of different addresses) but fast

Tags: proxy

I am curious if there is a browser or tool that changes the IP continuously but not multiple routes like Tor instead just like a single proxy. I think there might be a way of configuring Tor Browser like that too but I don't actually know anything about it.

Do you guys know any tool/browser like that?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using python modules. You can use an https proxy list which can be easily found using simple google search.

Then you will be able to emulate a different browser by using a module like Fake-useragent.

Here is a writeup which you can refer to :

https://codelike.pro/create-a-crawler-with-rotating-ip-proxy-in-python/